# how to retrieve property value in js file?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I am creating one asp page. In that page i defined one property like below

.cs

```
private long _sequence;
  public long Sequence { get { return _sequence; } set { _sequence = value; } }
```

Now i want to retrieve this property value in js file. Actually i can retrieve it in .aspx but i want it in .js file.

here is my js function and .aspx code which i am trying but it could not find property value

.aspx

```
<asp:Button ID="btnShowSimple" runat="server" Text="Notes Dialog" OnClientClick="NotesDialog(this)" />
```

.js

```
function NotesDialog(ctr) {
    var ControlName = document.getElementById(ctr.id);
    $("#btnShowSimple").click(function (e) {
        ShowDialog(false);
        e.preventDefault();
        LoadData("GetNotes", '"sequence":<%= this.Sequence %>');
    });
}
```

Anything I am missing?? If anyone have any idea about it than please help me..I am facing this problem since two days..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `js` files are static files on the server. You cannot use those `<%= %>` tags in them.
You could pass the property via a global javascript variable, that you set in your `aspx` page and use in your `js` file.

i.e.

.aspx

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      myProp = <%= this.Sequence %>;
  </script>
```

.js

```
function NotesDialog(ctr) {
    var ControlName = document.getElementById(ctr.id);
    $("#btnShowSimple").click(function (e) {
        ShowDialog(false);
        e.preventDefault();
        LoadData("GetNotes", '"sequence":' + myProp);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man...You solved mah problem...Thank you so much..:)

Comment: Don't declare arbitrary global variables in JavaScript!

Comment: @fredrik: arbitrary variable means?

Comment: Useless and random variables. The problem with declaring global variables in JavaScript is that they can easily be overwritten by other code. If you set a variable called myProp it has no meaning. myProp could be anything, and is just an ugly work around. Heres a good article about it: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad

Answer (score 1):

Nope you cannot do this in JS file as it is not processed by asp.net runtime. The best you can do is declare a variable in `aspx` and use it in `js` like:

**aspx:**

```
var _seq="<%= this.Sequence %>";
```

**JS:**

```
LoadData("GetNotes", '"sequence":' + _seq); //USE ASPX VARIABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to separate you JavaScript code from you HTML.

Instead och creating a `asp:Button` use an HTML button and set an data-attribute you can retrive.

`<button type="button" id="btnShowSimple" data-sequence="<%= this.Sequence %>">Notes Dialog</button>`

And in your javascript-file bind an click event to your button that picks up the data-sequence.

```
/** Put this in the bottom of you javascript file **/
(function (window) {
    var document = window.document,
        view;

view = {
    /**
    * Invoked in jQuery event context
    * @param e
    */
    bindClickEvent : function (e) {
        $("#btnShowSimple").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var sequence = $(this).data('sequence');

            ShowDialog(false);

            LoadData("GetNotes", '"sequence":' + sequence);

        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(view.bindClickEvent);

} (window));
```

From your current code you when you click the `asp:Button` you just bind a new click event and never execute it.

Also from some of the other answer, you should NEVER declare arbitrary global variables in JavaScript

Comment: You should still be able to use an asp:button. But don't use the OnClientClick attribute, bind the click event directly in javascript. Your current solution will bind a new click event for each time you click the button resulting in multiple executions of you click callback function

Comment: how to bind click event directly in javascript? I dont know about it. can you give sample?

Comment: Giving me an error. Object Expected in this line $(document).ready(view.bindClickEvent);

Comment: The js file needs to be included after you include your jquery.js file